# Mysql Encoding Problem

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

I have both utf8 and latin1 text in my database.

The problem is that i need to set:
set names utf8 or set names latin1 before i get the information in order to be shown correctly

My question is, how should i convert the entire database to utf8? Keep in mind that some rows have utf8, some latin1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need to set names to latin1? utf8 and latin1 do not interfere as far as i know. you should not have any problems setting your db to use utf8 encoding and still have iso chars displayed correct, should you?

Comment: no. it doesent work. my db is to utf8, but if i dont set set names utf8 the characters are not displayed corectly

Comment: latin1 is not a subset of utf8.